# What is the correct animation to change the color of a CustomPainter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, colors

In my flutter application I want to animate the color change (the color is a gradient) of two elements that inherit from a custom painter, this happens when a button is clicked.

My problem is that I can't find how to do it, since I understand that to animate an element a Tween is needed.

I cannot find a Tween that is correct for my case, since the color change is done in the CustomPainter conditionally.

The TweenColor class works, however I can't integrate it with a gradient and this doesn't work for me.

This effect is the one I want:

https://vimeo.com/578534813/e0f2d4ed73

This is what I have without using the Tween Color, it is fine, however, it is not the animated effect that I want.

https://vimeo.com/578538292/6e63a51060

As you can see, it is close to what is required, but it is not.

Thanks for your help, I leave the code.

> ScreenClass

```
class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
 }

 class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin 
 {
 late AnimationController controller;
 late Animation<double> opacity;


 @override
 void initState() {

 controller = new AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(seconds:2 ));
 opacity = Tween(begin: 0.1 ,end: 1.0).animate(controller);

 super.initState();
}

 @override
 void dispose() { 
 controller.dispose();
 super.dispose();
}



 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  controller.forward();

 final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context,listen: false);


 return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
       width: double.infinity,
       height: double.infinity,
       child: AnimatedBuilder(
         animation: controller,
         builder: (_,Widget? child){
           return Opacity(
             opacity: opacity.value,
             child: CustomPaint(
               painter: BackgroundPainter(provider:authProvider),
             ),
           );
         },
       ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: (){
              controller.reset();
              controller.forward();

              authProvider.flag = !authProvider.flag;

              
          },
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
          elevation: 12,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Text('Ingresar'),
        ),
      ),
      
      ])
);
}
 }
```

> ProviderClass

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
bool _flag = false;

bool get flag {
print(_flag);
return this._flag;
}

 set flag(bool state) => this._flag = state; 


}
```

> CustomPaintClass

```
class BackgroundPainter extends CustomPainter {
  
  AuthProvider provider;

 BackgroundPainter({required this.provider});

  final Gradient redColor = new LinearGradient(colors: <Color>[
    Colors.white12,
    Color(0xffF7A2A3),
  ]);

  final Gradient blueColor = new LinearGradient(colors: <Color>[
    Colors.white12,
    Color(0xff74BDD7),
  ]);


  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        
    final Rect rect = Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(55.0, 155.0), 
        radius: 180);

    /**
     * *Header*
     */
    
    Gradient color ;

    if(!provider.flag)
    color = redColor;
    else
    color = blueColor;

    final paint = new Paint()..shader = color.createShader(rect);

    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill; // .fill .stroke
    paint.strokeWidth = 20;

    final path = new Path();

    path.moveTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.20);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 0.95, size.height * 0.05, 0, size.height * 0.06);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);



    final Rect rect2 = Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(55.0, 155.0), // x = horizontal y  = vertical
        radius: 180);



    /**
     * *Footer*
     */

    Gradient color2 ;


    if(!provider.flag)
    color2 = blueColor;
    else
    color2 = redColor;

    final paint2 = new Paint()..shader = color2.createShader(rect2);

    paint2.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint2.strokeWidth = 30;

    final path2 = new Path();

    path2.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path2.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.80);
    path2.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 0.05, size.height * 0.95, size.width, size.height * 0.94);

    path2.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path2, paint2);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```